How do I add an extension to autodesk forge viewer?
I am trying to add an extension to autodesk forge viewer. Here is the expansion https://github.com/sermonis/autodesk-forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension
I added links to my index.html
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension/contents/main.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension/contents/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Developer JS -->
    <script src='forgeViewer.js'></script>

Here is my js file with adding viewer
var viewerApp;
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
        var accessToken = 'this_my_token';
        var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
        onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
    }
};

var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bG9yZDYwNi9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0';
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
    viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
    viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});


I don't understand what and how I need to connect in order for my extension to work

viewerApp.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
  viewerApp.loadExtension('DrawToolExtension');
});

